# What does "context" of "Widget build(BuildContext context)" mean in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

TL;DR:
**Is it the second parameter of build method or, name declaration of the BuildContext parameter in a conventional way?**

I'm learning the basic syntax of build method in Flutter by breaking down each element of "Widget build(BuildContext context)".

My understanding so far is below:

> - `@override: annotation`
> - `Widget build() {}: build method returns a widget`
> - BuildContext: a parameter/argument that contains information about the location in the tree at which this widget is being built

However, it's not been clear what the last word "context" exactly means even after I read related SO questions and official documents.

What I made sure so far is that the name "context" is changeable to whatever you want, meaning it doesn't have to be the same name as "context".

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From the docs, `BuildContext` is:

> A handle to the location of a widget in the widget tree.

`context` is a `BuildContext` instance that gets passed to the builder of a widget in order to let it know where it is inside the Widget Tree of your app.

One of the common uses is passing it to the `of` method when using an [Inherited Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html).

Calling `Something.of(context)`, for example, returns the `Something` relative to the closest widget in the tree that can provide you with that `Something`.

You can read more about `BuildContext` [here in the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html).

Comment: Thanks magicleon94! "context is a BuildContext instance", That's exactly what I wanted.  Just for confirmation, in this case, is "context" just a conventional instance name?

Comment: Yes, generally by `context` you refer to the instance passed from above. I had a problem once, I passed context inside a method calling it `context`, and the "conventional" context shadowed the one I passed. Calling the method argument not `context` but `somethingElse` solved the issue. So yes, I believe it's purely conventional!

Answer (score 1):

ya Baka context is just convectional name.....
you can also give some other name
like in given example
such as mycontext... is just as instance name... you  can say...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main()
{

runApp(myApp());

}

 class myApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext mycontext) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "my app",
      home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: While correct, this was explained 1.5 years ago with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can say context is the element of a widget tree
remember widget holds configuration and element makes the widget to be rendered in screen and context's know about each other that's why you can use theme or media query everywhere in your project