# why we pass context when we are navigating to next screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

why we pass **context** when we are *navigating to next screen* in **flutter**?

And what context really is?
Why we need context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "context" of "Widget build(BuildContext context)" mean in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54480937/what-does-context-of-widget-buildbuildcontext-context-mean-in-flutter)

Comment: Nope this is not the answer to my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does BuildContext do in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100196/what-does-buildcontext-do-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

The BuildContext in Flutter is an object that holds information about the context the Widget is in. Most importantly it holds where in the Widget-tree our Widget is located. This is why we need the BuildContext to get a certain Provider, ThemeData or MediaQuery for instance.

```
var media = MediaQuery.of(context);
```

Without the BuildContext belonging to the Widget we are in, Flutter has no way of knowing WHERE (in the Widget-tree) to look for the Data we are looking for.

Same goes for Navigation, we need to know where we are coming from, to go somewhere new.