# What is the 'context' argument in the Flutter 'push' method and how is it used?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am studying the topic of switching from one screen to another, but I don't understand what is the context argument. What does it mean in simple words? For example, using the .push() method:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const secondScreen()),
);
```

Comment: try [What does "context" of "Widget build(BuildContext context)" mean in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54480937/10157127)

Comment: you are providing the current widget's data like its position in the widget's hierarchy, and the state of the widget on top of which the navigation action has to happen. Context has information about the surrounding environment and services that the widget might need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BuildContext represents the location of a widget within the widget tree. It is an important concept that allows widgets to access and interact with other widgets and resources in the application.

Documentation:

> A handle to the location of a widget in the widget tree.
> BuildContext objects are passed to WidgetBuilder functions (such as
> StatelessWidget.build), and are available from the State.context
> member. Some static functions (e.g. showDialog, Theme.of, and so
> forth) also take build contexts so that they can act on behalf of the
> calling widget, or obtain data specifically for the given context.

I recommend this short video it's a very good explanation of the buildContext.
[short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIaaH87z1-g)